# PhantomJS & Chrome driver both not working with linux

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I have already followed similar questions and answers but none of them helped me.

I have setup code on bit bucket, Integrated everything in jenkins. Added Chromedriver and Phantom JS pakage to folder **/opt/**

Added **/opt/** permission to 777.

I tried to execute build with both [Chromedriver and Phantomjs] one by one but having same error.

**Stack Trace** :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /opt/chromedriver
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:117)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:118)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:291)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:117)
at Testcases.BaseTest.Setup(BaseTest.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:77)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Comment: What happens if you run chromedriver from the command line, eg. `> /opt/chromedriver`?

Comment: @jordanpg - Can you please tell me command? OR you are talking about maven command?

Comment: That is the command:  `/opt/chromedriver` then push enter.

Comment: It says : **/opt/chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found                          (required by /opt/chromedriver)
/opt/chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (                         required by /opt/chromedriver)
/opt/chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found                          (required by /opt/chromedriver)**

Comment: Looks like your operating system dependencies are out of date.  I would investigate updating gcc and glibc.